# Как перенести скрипт из HTML в JS файл?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот у меня работает такой скрипт, но он загрязняет HTML код:

```
onclick="return time_select(1004, 0, 1197);"
```

**Как его перенести в отдельный файл?** чтобы кнопки были вот такие:

```
<button>Хатха-йога</button>
```

**Код всего примера:**

```
<button onclick="return time_select(1004, 0, 1197);">Хатха-йога</button>

<table class="tg room-1004">
  <tr>
    <td class="item area-1011 trainer-1197"><a href="#">Хатха-йога</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<style>
.select {
  outline: 2px solid #D5110D;
  outline-offset: -1px;
}
</style>

<script>
function time_select(room, area, trainer) {
  $("table.room-" + room + " .item").removeClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .area-" + area).addClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .it").removeClass("select");
  $("table.room-" + room + " .trainer-" + trainer).addClass("select");
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: содержимое script вынесите в отдельный файл, например, myapp.js,  а в html укажите `<script src="myapp.js"></script>`, также из button удалите onclick. привязку обработчика можно сделать в myapp.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

изменить кнопку на

```
<button id="hathaYogaBtn">Хатха-йога</button>
```

Добавить в JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hathaYogaBtn').on('click', time_select(1004, 0, 1197));
});
```

---

Если у вас параметры функции динамические, то лучше так:

изменить кнопку на

```
<button id="hathaYogaBtn" data-p1="1004" data-p2="0" data-p3="1197">Хатха-йога</button>
```

Добавить в JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hathaYogaBtn').on('click', time_select($(this).data('p1'), $(this).data('p2'), $(this).data('p3')));
});
```

Comment: вместо `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` можно так `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: Ошибка в консоле вот такая Uncaught ReferenceError:

$ is not defined

Comment: @alex-lenk потому что вам нужно подключить jQuery. Вы же указали это библиотеку в вопросе, вот вам и написали пример с ее использованием

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, да действительности работает. Я почему-то был уверен на 100% что библиотека подключена.

Вопрос решен!

Answer (score 1):

Можете сделать так: создать в HTML кнопку потом добавить к неё id="btn"(например)
Далее в js коде получить объект этой кнопки посредством     vat btn = document.getElementById("btn") и далее все просто 
btn.onclick = function(){
 //Ваш код блока
};